# Validating a session from a url click

Tags: oracle-apex

The system that I work with sends an email to the users to allow them to view a ticket page.  The database asks for a log in if the user hasn't signed in yet, however, it also asks if they are.  I am looking for a way for validating that the user is already signed into the application and not require them to sign back in every time that open a new url.

Comment: You should spend some more time explaining the context of your problem. What you have described is not clear, and you cannot expect anyone to help you without a better and more detailed explanation.

Comment: **[What have you tried so far??](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried)**

Answer (score 0):

Stumbled upon this thread in the OTN Application Express forums. The solution there seems to be a fix for what you need!  [APEX 4.1 Login page kills existing session cookie](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2353817)
It looks for an existing cookie, checks session ids, and then allows resuming your session!

Still, watch out: closing the browser kills the cookies, so if your users do this, you'll need to teach them not to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that they have a browser open and they are authenticated to Apex at the time you send them the email?